# how to install magento 2.0 theme on shared hosting

Tags: magento2, theme, installation

Am building a store in `megento 2.0`, i successfully managed to install `magento 2.0` on shared hosting. I have a premium theme that i purchased from themeforest. But along the way i failed to install this purchased theme.

I have tried researching around the web but everyone is recommending to use composer but remember am on shared hosting, i have no access to the command line.

Please help and advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can just put yout theme in *app/design/frontend* (As you did in Magento1) but working without the command line access can be very hard.